# How to sort a character vector first by letter and then by number?

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a character vector that contains strings starting with letters and with numbers:

```
sample.condition
[1] "1_t"   "2_t"   "3_t"   "4_t"   "5_t"   "6_t"   "7_t"   "GFP_t" "1_t"  
[10] "2_t"   "3_t"   "4_t"   "5_t"   "6_t"   "7_t"   "GFP_t"
```

The final sorted vector should have the elements containing "GFP" in the 1st positions:

```
sample.condition
[1] "GFP_t"   "GFP_t" "1_t"   "2_t"   "3_t"   "4_t"   "5_t"   "6_t"   "7_t"   "1_t"  
[10] "2_t"   "3_t"   "4_t"   "5_t"   "6_t"   "7_t"
```

I have tried several sort arguments but got nowhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the strings not staring with a number. Create a logical index:

```
idx <- grepl("^[^0-9]", sample.condition)
```

Use this index for subsetting and sort the subsets. Then, combine both sorted subsets:

```
c(sort(sample.condition[idx]), sort(sample.condition[!idx]))

#  [1] "GFP_t" "GFP_t" "1_t"   "1_t"   "2_t"   "2_t"   "3_t"   "3_t"  
#  [9] "4_t"   "4_t"   "5_t"   "5_t"   "6_t"   "6_t"   "7_t"   "7_t"
```